# The Turing Machine in the proof of Time Hierarchy Theorem

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, turing-machines, time-complexity, computability

In the proof of the Time Hierarchy Theorem, Arora and Barak writes:

Consider the following Turing Machine $D$: “On input $x$, run for $|x|^{1.4}$ steps the Universal TM $U$ of Theorem 1.6 to simulate the execution of $M_x$ on $x$. If $M_x$ outputs an answer in this time, namely, $M_x(x)\in \{0,1\}$ then output the opposite answer (i.e., output $1−M_x(x)$). Else output $0$.” Here $M_x$ is the machine represented by the string $x$.

What if we give the encoding of $D$ as input to $D$? Then $D$ will accept exactly when $D$ will reject. So such a $D$ cannot even exist. Am I missing something?

Comment: Arora and Barak are two different people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no contradiction, since $D$ doesn't run in time $n^{1.4}$. In fact, what the proof of the time hierarchy theorem shows is that no *equivalent* Turing machine can run in time $n^{1.4}$, precisely because this will result in a contradiction. In other words, the language computed by $D$ lies outside of $\mathrm{DTIME}(n^{1.4})$. On the other hand, $D$ can be computed in time $O(n^{1.4} \log n)$. This shows that $$\mathrm{DTIME}(n^{1.4}) \subsetneq \mathrm{DTIME}(O(n^{1.4} \log n)).$$

(Usually $\mathrm{DTIME}(f(n))$ is defined as the class of problems which can be solved in time $O(f(n))$ rather than $f(n)$, the latter being the intended interpretation above. In that case the separation is between $\mathrm{DTIME}(f(n))$ and $\mathrm{DTIME}(n^{1.4} \log n)$ for any $f(n) = o(n^{1.4})$.)

Comment: In the proof in the book, this $D$ was defined to actually prove that $DTIME(n)\subset DTIME(n^2)$. So $D$ indeed lies in $DTIME(n^{1.4})$. Here is the link to the book: Page 84 in https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi6wOu5xrbzAhX-xDgGHUTnCPQQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fusers.cs.duke.edu%2F~reif%2Fcourses%2Fcomplectures%2Fbooks%2FAB%2FABbook.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2AHcaoNsueoBhaGr_vFPxe

Comment: Nevertheless, it can be used to prove a somewhat stronger separation.

Comment: Yes it can. But my question was what would happen when we give the string encoding of $D$ as input to $D$.

Comment: It would output $0$, since $D$ takes more than $n^{1.4}$ time.

Comment: Could you please explain why it would take more than $n^{1.4}$ time?

Comment: If it took less than $n^{1.4}$ time then we would reach a contradiction.

Comment: The "real" answer is that the universal Turing machine takes about $\Theta(n^{1.4} \log n)$ time to simulate another Turing machine for $n^{1.4}$ steps. Notice that $\Theta(n^{1.4} \log n)$ is generally more than $n^{1.4}$ (for large enough $n$).

Comment: Got it! Thank you.